# Remove specific lines from web.config using YAML pipelines

Tags: c#, azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

I want to delete some specific lines from my web.config while copying the file to the artifact using azure yaml pipelines.

Actual:

```
`<service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="">
     <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract=""/>
     <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
 </service>
<service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="">
     <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract=""/>
     <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
 </service>`
```

Expected: delete lines with comments

```
`<service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="">
     <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract=""/>
 </service>
<service behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior" name="">
     <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract=""/>
 </service>`
```

For information, I have the following task (CopyFile@2) in my current yml pipelines:

```
`- task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Copy web config into the Package
    condition: eq(variables.generateConfigs, true)
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(ReleasesPath.SourceFolderName)'
      Contents: |
        Web.config
      TargetFolder: '$(CopyPath.TragetFolderName)'
      CleanTargetFolder: false
      preserveTimestamp: true`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a Powershell task to remove the commented lines from the Web.Config file and then added the Copy task to Copy the Web.Config file to the destination.

Web.Config file :-

[image]

Below is my yaml code with Powershell and Copy task:-

```yaml
# Starter pipeline

# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.

# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:

# https://aka.ms/yaml

  

trigger:

- main

  

pool:

vmImage: windows-latest

  
  

steps:

- script: echo Hello, world!

displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

  

- script: |

echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.

echo See https://aka.ms/yaml

displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

  

- task: PowerShell@2

inputs:

targetType: 'inline'

script: |

Get-Location

Get-ChildItem .

  

- task: PowerShell@2

inputs:

targetType: 'inline'

script: |

$configPath ='$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Web.Config'

$content = Get-Content $configPath

$content = $content | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '<!--' }

$content | Set-Content $configPath

  

- task: CopyFiles@2

inputs:

SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

Contents: 'Web.Config'

TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

  

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1

inputs:

PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

ArtifactName: 'drop'

publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Output:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Opened the **Web.Config** file and the commented lines were removed by the PowerShell task like below:-

[image]

[image]